# unable to connect any specified mysql hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating one windows form application in c# which use MySQL database.
whenever I am inserting data through my form to specified "server ip"
it throws error like "unable to connect any specified MySQL".
when I sending data to localhost,it works. 
so can you guys please tell me how can I send data to specified "server IP".
Help me folks.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
{                             
        string connectionString =               
        @"DataSource=tcp:162.**.*.***;
        port=3306;
        Database=mysql_csharp;
        uid=root;
        password=***;";
        string query = "Insert into mysql_csharp.users   (firstname,lastname,message)values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "');";## Heading ##
        MySqlConnection condb = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmddb = new MySqlCommand(query, condb);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            condb.Open();
            myReader = cmddb.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            //this.BindGrid();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        this.Update();
```

Comment: your 162 box, that is a second box correct? So you are sitting on a box A. That is localhost. You can connect to it. But you cannot connect to box B.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string for mysql is correct.If it's correct,just check whether you have an access to the server by connecting from your machine.

Following article will help you
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

Comment: Hey.. 
Thanks for reply but I think my connection string is correct because whenever I changes "IP address" to localhost in connection string then it works I mean data successfully stored in db.
so problem is arise only when I use IP address.

Comment: Did you check whether you have access to that mysql server?

Ping 192.125.124.125 
[OR]
Telnet 198.125.124.101 3306

Comment: Yea , I have.
I can access MySQL server.

Comment: Please make sure whether you are able to access the DB server.Looks like you don't have enough permission to access the server.Please check whether you have the database at the server.Run ur visual studio with admin rights and try to connect.Debug the code and check where exactly it breaks